# Responsibility matrix(Raci) in enterprise-architecture

Tags: enterprise-architect, bpmn

I have pools and lanes with some activities within them in BPMN 2.0 Business Process Diagram. I want showing Lanes ( or pools) with their activity in Relationship Matrix.
I choose lanes (pools) in Source and activities in Target or vica versa in relationship matrix, but the relations could not be shown.
How can i select Link Type in relashionship matrix? How can I resolve my problem? how should I relate activities to lanes for showing relations in Relationship Matrix?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RACI (Resposible,Accountable,Consulted,Informed) matrix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33751689/raci-resposible-accountable-consulted-informed-matrix)

Answer (score 0):

You can't in this way. The relationship matrix is based on connections established between elements. But this is a structural relation. And this is already visible in the project browser. But of course there you can't play with that relation wizardry (which in the case of pools does not make sense anyway).

Comment: How Can create RACI (Resposible,Accountable,Consulted,Informed) matrix in Sparx Enterprise Architect?
In visual Paradigm, RACI chart can be created easily, based on lanes and associated activities within them.

Comment: Well, with a car you can drive. With a plane you can fly. VP is a car. EA is a plane (or vise versa if you like).