# RACI (Resposible,Accountable,Consulted,Informed) matrix

Tags: enterprise-architect

How Can create RACI (Resposible,Accountable,Consulted,Informed) matrix in Sparx Enterprise Architect? In visual Paradigm, RACI chart can be created easily, based on lanes and associated activities within them

Comment: Are you really going to ask the same question over and over again?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Responsibility matrix(Raci) in enterprise-architecture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33667675/responsibility-matrixraci-in-enterprise-architecture)

Answer (score 0):

The image below shows one possible way to do this.

I selected diagram type 'Custom' but I expect you could use many other diagram types if you prefer. I right-clicked on the diagram, selected 'Swim Lanes, Matrix, and Kanban' from the context menu, then used the 'Matrix' option to build the diagram.

[image: matrix diagram]